# Angular2 with webpack production: "Failed to load app/app.component.html"

Tags: angular, webpack

My project is based on [Angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter). It's currently with `Angular2 rc.4` and `webpack 1.13.1`. If I run it in dev mode, everything works well.

[image: dev mode result]

But if running under production mode, I get `Failed to load app/app.component.html` exception due to `GET http://localhost:8080/app/app.component.html 404 (Not Found)`.

[image]

I check the [webpack.common.js](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/config/webpack.common.js), [webpack.dev.js](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/config/webpack.dev.js) and [webpack.prod.js](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/config/webpack.prod.js) files. There is nothing special for the prod configuration and the html loader is actually in the shared `webpack.common.js` file. I'm seeking help about how to debug this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The angular2-webpack-starter uses the `angular2-template-loader` to keep track of html and style dependencies and, as far as I understand it, ends up changing your `templateUrl:` properties in your component to `template:` properties and actually inlines the HTML file there. So your app shouldn't even be calling for the html file. Did you alter the common config file to remove the `angular2-template-loader`? Its on line 143 in the common config (https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/config/webpack.common.js).

Also make sure your tsconfig.json is set up properly for the awesome loader, as `angular2-template-loader` needs the `useWebpackText` property set to true. See here (under Requirments): https://github.com/TheLarkInn/angular2-template-loader

Comment: Thanks. It turns out that I miss the `angular2-template-loader`. And by the way, I have to replace `templateUrl: '.app.component.html',` by `template: require('./app.component.html'),` and then the browse won't try to load `.html` files any more.

Comment: @BingLu The usage of `require` is not only necessary! `require` will import/inject the content of the files. But what angular want this to do behind the scene using `angular2-template-loader`. Just add `angular2-template-loader` to webpack loaders. The file webpack.common.js: `loaders: ['ts', 'angular2-template-loader']`